# Error when building Saxon/C for PHP

Tags: php, c++, c, xslt, saxon

When I try and build Saxon/C for PHP under Ubuntu 16.04 I am getting a bunch of after running the make command.

This is the first error:

```
/bin/bash /usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API/libtool --mode=compile g++  -I
. -I/usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/lib/Saxonica/S
axon-HEC/Saxon.C.API/include -I/usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API/main -I/u
sr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include
/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/
Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib  -
DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API/php_saxon.cp
p -o php_saxon.lo 
libtool: compile:  g++ -I. -I/usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API -DPHP_ATOM_
INC -I/usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API/include -I/usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-
HEC/Saxon.C.API/main -I/usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API -I/usr/include/ph
p/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/
usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php
/20151012/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Sax
on.C.API/php_saxon.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_saxon.o
/usr/lib/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC/Saxon.C.API/php_saxon.cpp:454:29: error: macro "RETURN_STRING" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1

php_saxon.cpp:3297:40: error: ‘xdmAtomicValue_create_handler’ was not declared in this scope
 xdmAtomicValue_ce->create_object = xdmAtomicValue_create_handler;
```

The above error messages is the last one of many.

The first make was stopped when the compiler didn't find the jni.h file. I copied the header-file into the folder (that might be wrong?)

Error message:

```
Saxon.C.API/SaxonProcessor.h:10:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
```

Second attempt stopped when the compiler didn't find the jni_md.h - again I copied the file to the folder.

```
php_saxon.cpp:5:
./jni.h:45:20: fatal error: jni_md.h: No such file or directory
```

Any directions on how to build this are welcome. I bet it is my lack of knowledge and not the fantastic software.

I am following the directions on this page:
http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html
and I have also tried using the phpize5.6 and phpize7.0

Comment: It's usually best to start with the first error message, not the last.  I find it not at all surprising that undeclared identifier errors accompany the compiler being unable to find a header file, and indeed, copying the header file into the project folder is a poor way to handle the problem.  Instead, you should add the header's own folder to the include file search path.  How you do that varies from compiler to compiler, but use of a `-I` option for that purpose is a fairly common convention for command-line compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, John. I have added the first error in the question above

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John. Adding the location of the jni should solve your problem. The troubleshooting guide should help you here. See: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml#troubleshooting
You have a few options here:

1) Edit the Makefile to include the jdkdir i.e.: -I$jdkdir/include -I$jdkdir/include/linux

2) Simply install gcj-jdk I have found to solve this problem

3) Copying the files jni.h and the jni_md.h files to the directory of Saxon/C code I have also found to work.